# Official way to query the number of instances in an Oracle RAC

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, cluster-computing, instances

According to [The Oracle FAQ](http://orafaq.com/wiki/RAC_FAQ), you can query the `SYS.V_$ACTIVE_INSTANCES` and/or `SYS.V_$THREAD` views to find the number of active RAC instances. I remember reading somewhere that the `V_$` views are internal to Oracle and subject to change without notification. Is this true? Is there an "official" way to find the number of running instances in a RAC database in a stored procedure? Is there a way to find out the total number of RAC instances for a database, running or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same oracle FAQ,

> To list the active instances from PL/SQL, use
>   DBMS_UTILITY.ACTIVE_INSTANCES().

and yes are "subject to change without notification": someone can draw out the power cable of one machine "without notification"

Comment: Thank you, that appears to work. And I meant "subject to change without notification" by Oracle, i.e. that Oracle could change the schema and my application would break.